# Argument null exception when using IEnumerable RestaurantData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);

Tags: c#, linq, datatables

1. Where sortColumn is the name of column (string) want to sort.
2. sortColumnDir is asc or desc oreder.

   ```
   var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();

   var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
   var modal = _repo.GetAllResturents();

   var RestaurantData = (from tempcustomer in modal
                         select tempcustomer);

   //Sorting    
   //RestaurantData = RestaurantData.OrderBy(sortColumn);

   if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
   {
       RestaurantData = RestaurantData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);

   }
   ```

   i am getting Argument null exception.
   Note : RestaurantData = RestaurantData.OrderBy(s=>s.Name); is working as expected but does not serve my purpose here. i want to sort on  the basic of sortColumn (column name). Please Suggest some better approach for this scenario.

Comment: `RestaurantData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir)` is not a proper way to perform sort ordering. Consider using `Select` then using `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`.

Comment: If statement will hit if sortColumnDir is null or empty.

Comment: Also worth to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet-iqueryablet. What you want to use actually called "dynamic LINQ", which requires `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it is working fine using System.Linq.Dynamic but why it is not a proper way to perform sort ordering. as i am using Linq so writing Select make any performance benefits?

Comment: By using standard `OrderBy` I could tell that's not proper way because  `System.Linq.OrderBy()` extension method requires lambda expression rather than string concatenation. The `System.Linq.Dynamic.OrderBy()` accepts string as parameter, hence just use proper library before using extension methods.

Comment: The error is rather clear. If you *debug* this, you'll probably see that one of the column names is `null`. Your check returns true only if *both* strings are null. `OrderBy` doesn't work with constant values like the one you passed anyway. It expects a *lambda* that is used to generate the order key